# Write a function from native javascript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering how can I rewrite this javascript function into jQuery but using `if`/`else` statements instead of `while`:

```
<textarea style="overflow-y: hidden;" onkeyup="expandtext(this);"></textarea>
```

```js
function expandtext(textArea){
    while (textArea.rows > 1 && textArea.scrollHeight < textArea.offsetHeight) {
        textArea.rows--;
    }

    while (textArea.scrollHeight > textArea.offsetHeight) {
        textArea.rows++;
    }
    textArea.rows++
}
```

Comment: Take a look here : http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/frudD

Comment: Vanilla (native) javascript will always be faster than jQuery. If it works in JS, why would you want to rewrite it in jQuery? Just curious.

Comment: @JeremyThille Because I am wondering how to increase ++ and decrease -- attribute "rows" using jQuery, anyway guys I will like to be more constructive on an answer and not to talk about why you want to do that and that ....

Comment: @RulerNature jQuery is not a language, it is just a library. Nothing ever changes with `++` or `--` or any other feature of JavaScript.

Comment: @RulerNature You keep demanding a thing that doesn't make sense and you don't seem to understand what you're actually asking. And instead of starting to hate on the site, how about you start clarifying what you're really trying to achieve? Using jQuery for your example is really comparable to having a boat anchor on a motorcycle: You **can** do it, but **why**? What do you want to achieve with it? jQuery **is a library**, and it really does **not** have **any component** that would improve the above example in **any way**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you appear to want it so badly, here it is

```
$.fn.expandText = function () {
    $.each(this, function (k, textArea) {
        while (textArea.rows > 1 && textArea.scrollHeight < textArea.offsetHeight) {
            textArea.rows--;
        }

        while (textArea.scrollHeight > textArea.offsetHeight) {
            textArea.rows++;
        }
        textArea.rows++
    });
}

$('textarea').expandText();
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7qoLsh78/)**

Additionally, I think I understand what you wanted to ask. In order to understand this you need a good understanding of javascript objects and document object model. There are special properties of objects in the DOM which affect how the objects are displayed (this is all done by your browser automatically), `rows` is one of those properties, and in order for the element on the page to change in height, which is the goal of this function, you need to change the property `rows` on the specific element. You can't do this with jQuery (or maybe you can, who knows) because it wraps your object in other objects. Even if it is possible, you are going to have to call a function on the wrapper object which is then going to access the DOM object and change it's property, which is what your function does in the first place, so why bother at all.

Comment: Except the OP wants the `while`s replaced with `if` statements... :)

Comment: @Andy Yeah, I don't get that.

Comment: @php_nub_qq ty for your time and good explain of this :) I will try to read more in order to understand better DOM objects .

Comment: You could actually refactor the function to use `if`/`else` and recursion to achieve a loop-like effect, just for the sake of showing that it is actually possible. (Disclaimer: Yes, I know how horrible that practise would be and that it should never be used.)